# Compilação do OpenCV não encontra os includes

Tags: c++, opencv, compilação

Eu estou tentando compilar um código simples só pra testar porém quando eu compilo tanto com g++ quanto com o clang++ eles falam que o a referência para o método não foi encontrado. Segui os passos deste guia oficial do OpenCV para instalação, ocorreu tudo bem e ainda executei o passo de testes com sucesso. Estou usando Ubuntu 18.04

- Código simples só para tentar compilar

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
int main(){
    cv::Mat image;
}
```

- Saída do g++ com o comando `g++ teste.cpp -o teste -I /usr/local/include/opencv4` :

```
/tmp/ccqJeAzC.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
teste.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccqJeAzC.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
teste.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x4b): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

- Saída para o clang usado o comando `clang++ teste.cpp -o teste -I /usr/local/include/opencv4` :

```
/tmp/teste-44c531.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
teste.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD2Ev]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/teste-44c531.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
teste.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x48): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Bom consegui corrigir porém não sei porque isso corrige meu problema. Eu apenas coloquei o seguinte no fim do comando `-lopencv_core` achei isso aqui https://answers.opencv.org/question/221603/undefined-reference-to-imread/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está linkando uma library necessária, no caso, como você mesmo solucionou, a opencv_core.

A flag -lopencv_core é repassada ao linker para que este procure pela library estática libopencv_core.a ou pela library dinâmica libopencv_core.so em seus diretórios padrões (e nos diretórios indicados com a flag -L) e depois faça a ligação com o arquivo encontrado.